# Design a transmitter class in C++: buffer data from server & send to client

Tags: c++, multithreading, client

I'm writing a class "Tmt" that acts between a server and clients through sockets. My Tmt class will receive data from server, build up a queue internally and perform some operation on the data in the queue before they are available to the client.

I have already setup the socket connection and I can call
receiverData(); // to get data from server

The client will use my class Tmt as follows:
Tmt mytmt=new Tmt();
mymt.getProcessedData(); //to get one frame.

My question is how to let the Tmt class keep receiving data from server in the background once it is created and add them to the queue. I have some experience in multi-thread in C, but I'm not sure how this "working in the background" concept will be implemented in a class in C++. Please advice, thanks!

Comment: Fair enough using that name for your SO question, but you're going to use something more readable than "Tmt" to name the real class, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to associate a thread with each instance of the class (perhaps by creating a thread in the constructor).  This thread continuously reads data from the network and adds the data to the queue as it becomes available.  If the thread is marked private (i.e. class clients aren't aware of its existence), then it will essentially be running "in the background" with no explicit intervention.  It would be up to the `Tmt` object to manage its state.

As for actual thread implementations in C++, you can just use Good ol' Pthreads in C++ just fine.  However, a much better approach would probably be to use the [Boost threading library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html), which encapsulates all the thread state into its own class.  They also offer a whole bunch of synchronization primitives that are just like the pthread versions, but substantially easier to use.

Hope this helps!

By the way - I'd recommend just naming the class `Transmit`.  No reason to be overly terse. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, multithreading is not the best solution for this kind of classes.

Introducing background threads can cause many problems, you must devise guards against multiple unnecessary thread creation at the least. Also threads need apparent initialize and cleanup. For instance, usual thread cleanup include thread join operation (wait for thread to stop) that could cause deadlocks, resource leaks, irresponsible UIs, etc.

Single thread asynchronous socket communication could be more appropriate to this scenario.

Let me draw sample code about this:

```
class Tmt {
...
public:
    ...
    bool doProcessing()
    {
        receiverData();
        // process data
        // return true if data available
    }

    T getProcessedData()
    {
        // return processed data
    }
}
```

Tmt class users must run loop doing doProcessing, getProcessedData call.

```
Tmt myTmt;
...
while (needMoreData)
{
    if (myTmt.doProcessing())
    {
        myTmt.getProcessedData();
        ...
    }
}
```

If Tmt users want background processing they can easily create another thread and doing Tmt job in there. This time, thread management works are covered by Tmt users.

If Tmt users prefer single thread approach they can do it without any problem.

Also noted that famous curl library uses this kind of design.